# How to show both overlapping lines in in chartjs

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am trying to create a line graph with multiple data datasets, 
but for some datasets, there are chances the values match in which case the lines overlap and the set defined first is shown, At the moment Green and Red are overlapping and green is defined first hence its color is shown

img-> https://nimb.ws/b7jvVH

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
// The type of chart we want to create
type: 'line', // also try bar or other graph types

// The data for our dataset
data: {
    labels: $.getMonths(year+'-01-01',year+'-12-31'),
    // Information about the dataset
datasets: [
    {
        label: "Converted",
        borderColor: 'Green',
        data: leadsConvertedAtCountPerMonthPerYear,

    },
    {
        label: "Contacted",
        borderColor: 'red',
        data: leadsContactedAtCountPerMonthPerYear,

    },
    {
        label: "Assigned",
        borderColor: 'royalblue',
        data: leadsAssignedAtCountPerMonthPerYear,

    },


]
},

// Configuration options
options: {
layout: {
  padding: 10,
},
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Reports for '
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Precipitation in mm'
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Month of the Year'
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

});[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unijk.png)

I Want the overlapping lines to show both colors

Answer (score 2):

You could try making the colors semi-transparent. E.g. instead of green use `rgb(0,128,0,0.5)`